# How to get click event of DrawerArrowDrawable

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using `DrawerArrowDrawable` to animate the hamburger icon during the opening and closing of Navigation drawer. Following is the code snippet I used for that:

```
DrawerArrowDrawable drawerArrow = new DrawerArrowDrawable(this);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(drawerArrow)
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Now when I open a fragment I use `actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_icon);` & `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` in that very fragment, to change the navigation icon as a back icon. The icon changes but the functionality of that button stays same i.e., it opens the navigation drawer, but I want to go back to the previous fragment (by using `popBackStack`).

I tried to override `onOptionsItemSelected` :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

But the control never reaches in the above block when I press the navigation icon.

If I get to know that **How to intercept the click event of DrawerArrowDrawable?** I would be able to run `popBackStack` and do what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                       if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                       fm.popBackStack();
                       }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Hi @Ankit, thanks for your answer, but there is one issue, after using your code the navigation drawer fails to open on the button click.

Comment: Hi @AnasAzeem In onDetach method of fragment from  where you are doing popBackStack you need to again set the NavigationDrawer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this listener inside the Navigation Drawer Activity:

```
private FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener mOnBackStackChangedListener = new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        setActionBarArrowDependingOnFragmentsBackStack();
    }
};
```

Then create this method:

```
public void setActionBarArrowDependingOnFragmentsBackStack() {
    int backStackEntryCount = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(backStackEntryCount == 0);
}
```

Now override these methods:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled() && mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home && getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    getFragmentManager().removeOnBackStackChangedListener(mOnBackStackChangedListener);

}
```

Finally add this line inside your onCreate() method:

```
getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(mOnBackStackChangedListener);
```

Comment: Hi @Jofre, thanks for your answer but it didn't work for me. Even in the subfragmnents, clicking the icon opens the navigation drawer.

Comment: When you make a fragment transaction, you add the fragment to the backstack right?
    `ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();`

Comment: Yeah. I do add to back stack